# Animate view alongside NavigationView transition

Tags: ios, animation, swiftui, navigation

I have a custom progress view that indicates what view the user is currently on inside the navigation stack.

[image]

I am wanting to animate the progress view alongside my NavigationView transitions.
That is to say, as the views transition from one to another inside the NavigationView the progress view should also animate to the next/previous section.

I want this to work by detecting the percentage of transition and updating the progress accordingly, that way if the user begins swiping back the animation will update based on the users current swipe.

This can be achieved inside UIKit by having a custom UINavigationController, then adding a selector to the interactivePopGestureRecognizer and then reading the percentageComplete variable on the UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator on said navigation controller.

However I have yet to find any SwiftUI alternative, does such a thing exist yet/is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, you need a state variable that tracks the current navigation level. The state variable should be updated whenever the level changes. One way is to use `.onAppear` on the destination views.

The example below shows it working this way. `NavigationView` is deprecated, so the example uses a `NavigationStack` instead:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    let nLevels = 7
    @State private var currentLevel = 1

    private func viewForLevel(level: Int) -> some View {
        VStack(spacing: 40) {
            Text("This is level \(level)")
            if level < nLevels {
                NavigationLink("Go to level \(level + 1)", value: level + 1)
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            withAnimation {
                currentLevel = level
            }
        }
        // If onAppear is not called when navigating back then
        // onDisappear can be used as fallback.
        // Not found to be needed with NavigationStack and iOS 16.4
//        .onDisappear {
//            if currentLevel == level {
//                withAnimation {
//                    currentLevel = level - 1
//                }
//            }
//        }
    }

    private func progressIndicator(currentLevel: Int) -> some View {
        HStack(spacing: 6) {
            ForEach(1...nLevels, id: \.self) { level in
                Rectangle()
                    .frame(height: 6)
                    .foregroundColor(level <= currentLevel ? .teal : Color(white: 0.9))
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            progressIndicator(currentLevel: currentLevel)
            NavigationStack {
                viewForLevel(level: 1)
                    .navigationDestination(for: Int.self) { level in
                        viewForLevel(level: level)
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: NavProgress]

You could also associate the `NavigationStack` with a `path` and read the current level from the end of the path, instead of using a separate state variable. I tried this, but found that the change was delayed when navigating back. So a separate state variable probably works better (as used here).